# Searching for Social security number using Lucene 4 regexp

Tags: regex, lucene

I'm trying to use Lucene 4 Regexp query to find social security numbers. If the field is analyzed using the StandardAnalyzer or the EnglishAnalyzer, is there still some way to match strings like `222-33-4444` or `222 33 4444`.

As far as I can see, these analyzers tokenize the components of the SSN, and then there's no way to catch consecutive matches for the 3 components. Ideally, I'd like `222 33 4444` to match something like `"/[0-9]{3}/ /[0-9]{2}/ /[0-9]{4}/"` but it doesn't seem to be perhaps because phrase queries do not work with regexp's (yes?) Any suggestions?

Comment: May we know __why__ you are trying to find SSNs?

Comment: its a forensic type software for people to find and redact sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply have a field of identifiers, or some such, use a `StringField`, or some other untokenized field, in which case a simple `RegExpQuery` is simple enough to define.

If you are trying to pull them out of a full-text field, which must be tokenized (and I assume this is the case), you can use the [`SpanQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanQuery.html) API to construct the appropriate query:

```
SpanQuery span1 = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", "[0-9]{3}")));
SpanQuery span2 = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", "[0-9]{2}")));
SpanQuery span3 = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", "[0-9]{4}")));

Query query = new SpanNearQuery({span1, span2, span3}, 0, true);

searcher.search(query, maxResults)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **INTERVAL** flag:

```
/<000-999>/ /<00-99>/ /<0000-9999>/
```

**[> INTERVAL](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html#INTERVAL)**

Comment: unfortunately this will match any document with a string of 2, 3, or 4 digits anywhere. I need to match consecutive strings of 3, 2, 4 digits.

Comment: then why not do `/<000-999><00-99><0000-9999>/`

Comment: that doesn't match 222 33 4444

Comment: is it supposed to match `222 33 4444`? In your question you said you want `222 33 4444` to match the regex — which is it? did you try the interval with spaces? `/<000-999> <00-99> <0000-9999>/`, that might help.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know about lucene, but this regex works:

```
'\d{3}[ \-]\d{2}[ \-]\d{4}'
```

It matches both:

`222 33 4444`
and 
`222-33-4444`

Comment: Unfortunately, won't work with an analyzed field in Lucene.  Usually it's safe enough to bet that you don't really *need* to know the attendant details, because regex is regex, but not in this case.

Comment: @femtoRgon `SpanQuery` really worked in my case. Thanks a lot. I was looking solution since last few days and I could not reach to your answer if you did not add comment yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942207/pattern-matching-in-elastic-search