# pattern matching in elastic search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

Continuing from my earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922057/how-to-match-the-pattern-like-xxx-xx-xxxx-in-order-to-look-for-documents-with), I have changed the query as according to femtoRgon's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313051/elasticsearch-and-regex-queries) some characters and anchors are not supported by elastic search.

I am looking the way to match the pattern like "xxx-xx-xxxx" in order to look for documents with social security numbers using `elastic search`.

Let’s suppose, in indexed documents, I would like to find all those documents that has social security numbers that matches "xxx-xx-xxxx" pattern.

Sample code for indexing the document:

```
InputStream is = null;
    try {
      is = new FileInputStream("/home/admin/Downloads/20121221.doc");
      ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
      Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
      parser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata, new ParseContext());
      }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (is != null) is.close();
    }
```

Sample Code for searching

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilderFullText = null;
queryBuilderFullText = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
                        FilterBuilders.regexpFilter("_all", "[0-9]{3}?[0-9]{2}?[0-9]{4}"));
SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder;
            requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch()
                    .setIndices(getDomainIndexId(project))
                    .setTypes(getProjectTypeId(project))
                    .setQuery(queryBuilderFullText);
SearchResponse response = requestBuilder.execute().actionGet(ES_TIMEOUT_MS);
            SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
if (hits.getTotalHits() > 0) {
System.out.println(hits.getTotalHits());
 } else {
                return 0l;  
        }
```

I am getting hits for following:

```
45-555-5462
457-55-5462
4578-55-5462
457-55-54623
457-55-5462-23
```

But as per my requirement, it should only return "457-55-5462" (based on pattern matching "xxx-xx-xxxx").

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to match the pattern like "xxx-xx-xxxx" in order to look for documents with social security numbers using elastic search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922057/how-to-match-the-pattern-like-xxx-xx-xxxx-in-order-to-look-for-documents-with)

Comment: @funkwurm I have changed the query as per the femtoRgon's post because some characters and anchors are not supported by elastic search. So I am here with my updated search query.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after flagging but I can't undo the flag, sorry on that one. I answered as well, hope that gives what you need :)

Comment: @funkwurm No problem. Thanks for your help but unfortunately `\d` or `\\d` characters and `^` or `$` anchors are not supported by elastic search.

Comment: Changed my answer accordingly

Comment: `[^0-9-][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}[^0-9-]` still not work. Returning all instead of only one `457-55-5462` from my above example.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as `^`, `$` and `\d` can't be used, I would do this:

```
[^0-9-][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}[^0-9-]
```

Or in Java:

```
FilterBuilders.regexpFilter("_all", "[^0-9-][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}[^0-9-]"));
```

Which checks that before or after the found number are no other numbers or dashes. It does require there be *some* character before and after the match though, so this won't capture documents that have the social security number as the **very beginning** or **very end**.

**[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQ6fL6/2)**

Comment: @Ashish let's talk about the answer in the comments of that answer :P You can see from the Regex101 demo that it works with all 3 regex flavors. I'm guessing the issue is with `FilterBuilder` or another part of the `elastic search`.

Comment: Okay. Yes it's possible that issue is with elastic search. I am looking that issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think- issue is with indexing as When it indexed, it's not indexed as one term "457-55-5462" but instead as 3 terms: "457", "55" and "5462". That's why my term search cannot find this term. `elastic search` removes hyphens when indexing. :(

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Comment: is there any way t0 search `xxx xxxx xx` instead of `xxx-xxxx-xx`?

Comment: `xxx-xx-xxxx` is not `xxx-xxxx-xx`, but sure you could replace the `-` after the `{3}` and `{2}` with a space. I'm reading a bit of their regex engine but making little sense. They say `ababab` does not match `(...)+` as if there are not 3 characters in that string?

Comment: I have replaced `-` with a space but unfortunately did not work. But I really appreciate your help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add `-` before `?` in your regex and also use anchors if necessary.

```
"[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}"
```

OR

```
"^[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}$"
```